# How to setup terminal environment variables for the Terminal plugin within Android Studio?

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea, android-studio

The Terminal plugin within Android Studio does not have any of the environment variables set in my user profile (i.e. .bashrc or .bash_profile) on OS X. Bringing-up the Terminal pane within the IDE, and attempting to use adb results in the following:

```
MacBook-Pro:app user$ adb
bash: adb: command not found
MacBook-Pro:app user$
```

Comment: Start Android Studio itself from the Terminal using `open -a /Applications/...` command. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891.

Comment: Starting from Terminal works, but is inconvenient. I've tried using the launchctl method and modifying the Info.plist from the answers you linked with no success. I presume this is a problem where Android Studio is starting the Terminal process but isn't passing its environment variables, nor does it follow typical shell setup.

Comment: That is correct. IntelliJ IDEA 12 also doesn't read terminal environment on Mac, but it was addressed in IDEA 13. Android Studio should just merge this fix.